# CRL and Windows certificate store

Tags: .net, cryptography

I need to get CRL from windows store (windows store for X509Certificate represent X509Store). I try such code:

```
string storName = "CA";//such store is exist
WinCertStorage = new X509Store(storName, storLoc);
WinCertStorage.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
foreach (X509Certificate2 cer in WinCertStorage.Certificates)
{
      if (cer.Version == 2)
           //certificate with version 2 can be CRL
}
```

But there is no CRL in X509Store that i opened.
Using mmc, I imported into "CA" store some CRL, but my code doesn't see it.

Can I get CRL with standart System.Security.Cryptography namespace? What do i need to use if I can't?
I need solution for .Net. Thank you.